# Linear algebra: what is the purpose of passive transformation matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

I am following the book: 3d Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development. I understand that to rotate a vector, you have to construct a matrix with rows (or columns) made of the new basis vectors and multiply the matrix with the vector intended for rotation. It is also intuitive that rotating a vector by x degree is similar to rotating the basis by -x degree. But when I create a matrix of the basis rotated by -x degree, and multiply it to the vector, I get something different from the result of rotating the object. Why does this happen?

Comment: Why close this important question ?

Comment: You are in front of the versatility alias/alibi (matrix defining a transformation vs.  matrix defining coordinates changes) that you will find well explained in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).